# overheating on lenovo ideapad z710; kubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, overheating

my problem is that, my laptop is entirely new and it has

```
    sensors
    acpitz-virtual-0
    Adapter: Virtual device
    temp1:        +74.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
    temp2:        +74.0°C  
    coretemp-isa-0000
    Adapter: ISA adapter
    Physical id 0:  +73.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 0:         +73.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 1:         +69.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 2:         +72.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 3:         +72.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

too high temperature.

```
    :~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core         
    Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
            Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3809
            Kernel driver in use: i915
    --
    01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
            Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3809
    07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565         
    Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Does anybody have the same problem as me? According to the specifications it ought to have 36 degrees.

---

It's a bit better.

```
temp1:        +58.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
temp2:        +58.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +57.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +54.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +53.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +56.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +57.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

---

It is not almost perfect. After using my laptop for several hours it is still bad. I just use mozilla, okular and libre office.

```
    temp1:        +74.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
    temp2:        +74.0°C  

    coretemp-isa-0000
    Adapter: ISA adapter
    Physical id 0:  +76.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 0:         +69.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 1:         +69.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 2:         +73.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 3:         +76.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

    thinkpad-isa-0000
    Adapter: ISA adapter
    fan1:           0 RPM
```

Comment: What kind of load is it under while overheating and is it overheating enough to shut itself down? (You may wish to add those to your question as it may help others help you diagnose the problem.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: You can look up how to adjust which graphics card is used, which may help.

Comment: What do you mean? Where can I look up? I have the Intel 4600 (i7-4710MQ) and the Nvidia 840M 2GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Nvidia proprietary driver this way:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

Your both graphics adapters consume power. that causes overheating.

And your discrete adapter does not work without the driver.

You can switch to the powersave Intel adapter by:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

then log off and log on.

Comment: It is not almost perfect. After using my laptop for several hours it is still bad. I just use mozilla, okular and libre office.

Comment: What does `prime-select query` output?

Comment: r:~$ sudo prime-select nvidia
Info: the nvidia profile is already in use

Comment: Is this an exact command?

Comment: Along with nvidia driver, install Thermald and TLP if not already there, make sure to install TLP via its PPA and also install ThinkPad Extras via the PPA.

Comment: Result is more worse: core 3 is most used and the laptop temperature is higher than earlier: After installing:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

Comment: I switched off the dropbox and now I am at around 50degrees ...

Comment: cpulimit -e dropbox -l 10

Comment: sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-tools tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter